# PrusaSlicer: How do I preserve the location of (interlocking) parts in a muliti-part model exported from OnShape / Blender?

Tags: slicing, prusaslicer, multi-material

How do you import a multi-part object into PrusaSlicer without losing the position of the parts? For example, I want to print a two-material interlocking structure like this:

[image: Two-part object with interlocking dovetails]

I've tried exporting this from my CAD software (OnShape) as a mesh (STL or OBJ) but when I import it into PrusaSlicer (v2.7.0) the result is either a single object with no internal walls:

[image: Screenshot of PrusaSlicer 2.7.0 showing a single featureless cube model]

or (3MF) two objects placed on the build plate individually, so they no longer interlock:

[image: Screenshot of PrusaSlicer 2.7.0 where the two parts have been placed onto the build plate individually]

If I use a STEP file it at least preserves the position of the parts within a single object, and there are some internal walls, but no internal top and bottom layers which I want for structural reasons (in this case the dovetail will simply crush in the XY plane if the part is tensioned in the Z axis):

[image: Screenshot of PrusaSlicer showing a sliced preview of a single object with two parts]

What's a good way to import multiple parts and have them "print in place", like they were in the original design?

Answer (score 3):

I've found **a** way to do this, which I'll document here in case it helps someone else in the future.

- Export your parts as a single STEP file
- Import that STEP file into PrusaSlicer
- Set **Print Settings > Multiple Extruders > Advanced > Interface shells**

  - (You need to be in **Expert** mode to see this option)

[image: Screenshot of PrusaSlicer 2.7.0 showing the Interface Shells option]

The STEP file adds the internal walls, and this **interface shells** option adds the internal **top and bottom** layers I was missing:

[image: Screenshot of PrusaSlicer 2.7.0 showing sliced preview of a two-part print where interior layers / floors can be seen]

Answer (score 0):

Despite how featureless the STL mesh looks when imported, all the data is there and you can split it to parts using the right click menu. I feel silly for now having spotted this before .

[image: PrusaSlicer 2.7.1 showing a featureless cube with a right click menu where "Split > To Parts" has been selected]

The result is exactly as I had hoped:

[image: PrusaSlicer 2.7.1 sliced view showing a two colour print and an object with two parts in the object list]

My take away is that PrusaSlicer *does not* always prompt you to split your important mesh into multiple parts; so its always worth attempting to split to parts using the menu after import.